# JS If Else madnes

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Ok I am relatively new to JS and jQuery, but have plenty of experience with other languages to know this should be alright. And it's starting to drive me mad.

Can somebody, please, explain to me why the code won't fire the second condition in this block? Am I missing something?

```
if (element === '#fs1' || element.attr('id') === "fs1")
{
    $("#fs1liuwc").show("slow"); 
}
else if (element === '#fs2' || element.attr('id') === "fs2")
{ 
    $("#fs2liuwc").show("slow");
}
else if (element === '#fs3' || element.attr('id') === "fs3")    
{ 
    $("#fs3liuwc").show("slow"); 
}
```

So the first one where the element is #fs1 is ok, everything works fine, but on the second and third one it just skips the rest of the script. I am calling this function from this one:

```
function ClickResize(sender)
{
   $(sender).click(function()
   {
     ResizeElement(sender);  
   });
}
```

Which is written in the:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
   ClickResize('#fs1');
   ClickResize('#fs2');
   ClickResize('#fs3');
});
```

Comment: What is `element` in your first code block?  Is it a string or an element?  If its an element, why are you testing it for strict equality with a string?  If its a string, why are you trying to call `.attr` on it as if it is an element?

Comment: Thanks Amy, I got three <section id="fs1" class="fs">

Comment: @Levidoom, where do you assign element? can you give us a small runnable snippet which reproduces your issue?

Comment: you use element === "fsx" and then element.attr(), soooooo, element does not exist. you can not compare element to string at all. and your element.attr() will work if you fetch element first with $("#id")

Comment: Ok I get that, but what bugs me to point of maddens is only the first element works, and all others don't . Will try all the suggestions

Comment: Thank you everyone, Armin pointet me to the flaw, switched the call ClickResize('#fs1'); to ClickResize($('#fs1'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `element` can be either string or DOM element, when `element` is a string, attempting to call `element.attr('id')` will die immediately with a `TypeError` (because `element.attr` doesn't exist).

You need to either ensure `element` is one consistent type, or type check it before trying to call the function. The minimalist fix might be to change each test of the form:

```
if (element === '#fs1' || element.attr('id') === "fs1") {
```

to:

```
if (element === '#fs1' || (element.attr && element.attr('id') === "fs1")) {
```

as merely loading `.attr` will succeed, but return `undefined` when it lacks the method/attribute, bypassing the attempt to *call* `attr` (which raises the exception).

Comment: Thank you, fixed it at some other point but this is very helpful.

Comment: @Levidoom: Your fix mentioned [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952081/js-if-else-madnes/59952255#comment106023925_59952081) was basically the "ensure `element` is one consistent type" solution, so it works either way. :-)

Comment: Yes it does, JS does not suit me one bit, it's all loosy-goosy, blah. Thank god for Blazor.

Answer (score 0):

before the code block, console.log element, so you understand what is going wrong.

```
console.log(element);

if (element === '#fs1' || element.attr('id') === "fs1")
{
    $("#fs1liuwc").show("slow"); 
}
else if (element === '#fs2' || element.attr('id') === "fs2")
{ 
    $("#fs2liuwc").show("slow");
}
else if (element === '#fs3' || element.attr('id') === "fs3")    
{ 
    $("#fs3liuwc").show("slow"); 
}
```

Also, it is not celar (maybe is just because of how you expressed it) why you are doing ResizeElement(**sender**);  and then you check for **element**.